# Problems importing JSON data with R

Tags: json, r

I'm using the jsonlite library to try to get some JSON data and turn it into a data frame that I could use, but so far it hasn't worked. I've tried three methods so far:

```
testData = fromJSON("<json file location>")
```

Which outputs:

```
Error in feed_push_parser(readBin(con, raw(), n), reset = TRUE) : 
parse error: trailing garbage
      n_reply_to_status_id":null}  {"contributors":null,"text":"Te
                 (right here) ------^
```

So I figured that if the quotes caused error, I'd just have to remove them:

```
singleString <- paste(readLines("<json file location>"), collapse=" ")
singleString = gsub('"', "",singleString)
singleString = fromJSON(singleString)
```

Which outputs:

```
Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                  {contributors:null,text:A colour
                 (right here) ------^
```

It seems to be pointing to an 'o' in the text. If I delete that 'o' it just points to the 'n' that comes after it.

My last attempt I read on a forum post of someone having a similar problem that it should solve it:

```
stream = stream_in(file("<json file location>"))
```

I was pretty happy to see that this did not return an error and that a data frame named "stream" had been added to memory, but when I tried to view that data frame...

```
> View(stream)
Error in View : 'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]
```

I'm not exactly sure what this means or what I could do about it in this situation.

If you have an idea of I could get this data loaded correctly, I would deeply appreciate it. Thanks!

**EDIT:** Here is the JSON data in question: https://gist.github.com/geocachecs/f68d769aeed8e019a26cc230559bbf7f

Comment: It's probably improperly formed JSON, though it's impossible to say without the text. You can check with `jsonlite::validate`.

Comment: @alistaire Sorry, I should have posted the data in the first place. You can see it here: https://gist.github.com/geocachecs/f68d769aeed8e019a26cc230559bbf7f

Comment: Posted json is not valid as brace enclosed `{..}` items must be part of a larger comma-separated collection.